# How to query to select a struct of array of struct column within a dataframe in Impala?

Tags: sql, arrays, select, struct, impala

How would I query to select length(int) which is within the array 'details' which is within the 'packets' column? Hopefully, the image attached will explain better than me!

I've tried `SELECT packets.details.length FROM test.ssh_data` which doesn't work.

This gives me the following error:

```
illegal column/field reference 'packets.details.length' with intermediate collection 'details' of type 'ARRAY<STRUCT<datestamp:STRING,length:INT>>
```

Thank you in advance!

[image: description of test.test_data]

Comment: Table structure , sample data and expected result would be more helpful.

Comment: have you tried `size(arr_col)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Impala nested types support, arrays and maps are treated as nested tables. You need to reference them in the FROM clause to unnest them. In that case you can add the array to the from clause, taking care to refer to it via `sd`, the alias of the table it's inside. E.g.

```
SELECT d.length FROM test.ssh_data sd, sd.packets.details d
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I gave this a go but gives no results? I also tried to add another column to this just to see if that column indeed does not have any values i.e.    `SELECT d.length sd.datestamp FROM test.ssh_data sd, sd.packets.details d`    but that also produces no results even though I know datestamp does indeed have values :/

Comment: Ah, you might want to change it to "FROM test.ssh_data sd, LEFT JOIN sd.packets.details d". The first version only returns rows if there are elements in the nested collection, so could be filtering out some of the top-level rows.